# Passing data back from php to ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

How can I pass data from a php of then rows back to ajax ?

PHP

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM picture order by rand() LIMIT 10';
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($rec = mysql_fetch_array($result,  MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

$url[]=$rec['pic_location'];
$name[]=$rec['name'];
$age[]=$rec['age'];
$gender[]=$rec['gender'];


}

echo json_encode($url);
echo json_encode($name);
echo json_encode($age);
echo json_encode($gender);
```

Ajax

```
$(".goButton").click(function() {
   var dir =  $(this).attr("id");
   var imId = $(".theImage").attr("id");

   $.ajax({
      url: "viewnew.php",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
         current_image: imId,
         direction    : dir
      },
      success: function(ret){
          console.log(ret);
          var arr = ret;
          alert("first image url: " + arr[0][0] + ", second image url: " + arr[0][1]);  // This code isnt working
          alert("first image Name: " + arr[1][0] + ", second image name: " + arr[1][1]);
          $(".theImage").attr("src", arr[0]);
          if ('prev' == dir) {
            imId ++;
         } else {
            imId --;
         }
         $("#theImage").attr("id", imId);
      }
   });

});
});
</script>
```

My question is how can I display the values here ? The Alert message is giving me "Undefined" ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do something along these lines.

## PHP

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM picture order by rand() LIMIT 10';
$res = mysql_query($query);

$pictures = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
  $picture = array(
    "pic_location" => $row['pic_location'],
    "name"         => $row['name'],
    "age"          => $row['age'],
    "gender"       => $row['gender']
  );
  $pictures[] = $picture;
}

echo json_encode($pictures);
```

## JS

```
...
$.ajax({
  ...
  dataType: "json",
  ...
  success: function(pictures){
    $.each(pictures, function(idx, picture){
      // picture.pic_location
      // picture.name
      // picture.age
      // picture.gender
    });
  }
});
...
```

Comment: Thankyou :)  ,  Would the `echo json_encode($picture);` be returning just the 1st row or all the 10 rows from the database ?

I just tried it , its echoing just the 1's row ?

Comment: One more question , We get our response and that object is stored in variable pictures.   Why doesn't `pictures(3).name` give me the name of the 3rd record ? How could I access that ?

Comment: Should be `pictures[2].name` for the third, since `pictures` should be an array.

Answer (score 2):

You can't put multiple `echo` statements for the AJAX response:

```
echo json_encode($url);
echo json_encode($name);
echo json_encode($age);
echo json_encode($gender);
```

Join your arrays and send a single response:

```
$arr = $url + $name + $age + $gender;
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this using a single Array:

```
$pics = array();

while ($rec = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  $pics[$rec['id']]['url'] = $rec['pic_location'];
  $pics[$rec['id']]['name']=$rec['name'];
  $pics[$rec['id']]['age']=$rec['age'];
  $pics[$rec['id']]['gender']=$rec['gender'];
}

echo json_encode($pics);
```

Comment: @srinivasan - Thanks , But i wanted to send the entire 10 rows of a database back ? I think this would just send the 1's row ? Isnt it ?

Comment: @Alexander and Adi Mathur, I've corrected the errors now. Please see the updated code.