# Load php content from js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#start').click(function(){
        $('#mainbody').html('<?php include "content1.php";?>');
    });
});
```

Instead of loading contents of content1.php in DOM it adds a comment like this :

```
<div class="row" id="mainbody">
    <!--?php include "content1.php";?-->
</div>
```

Comment: AJAX... read about it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is an uber duplicate. OP has no mercy for other users on this site and must ask again and again regardless of the work others did already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#mainbody').load('content1.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches to do this. The first one is, like I said in the comment, to make an AJAX call to the proper content page, check its response, and if it's all good, modify the DOM appropriately.

The other approach is something I'd suggest you not to do if you plan to have a lot of different 'contents'. I'm saying that you can preload all the contents into separate, hidden DOM elements (divs, for example), and then modify the click function you have to show the needed element and hide the others.

Of course, choosing the best approach strongly depends on what your app is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do an AJAX call.

Check out this question [Passing data back from php to ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960471/passing-data-back-from-php-to-ajax)

Should be a good example on helping you with getting things going. If you still have problems show us your progressed work and we will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You need AJAX call

Sample code to get started.

```
// fire off the request to /form.php
    request = $.ajax({
        url: "/form.php",
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData
    });

    // callback handler that will be called on success
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // log a message to the console
        console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
    });

    // callback handler that will be called on failure
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // log the error to the console
        console.error(
            "The following error occured: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
    });
```