# How to put all of the images from folder into CSS box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I have a problem to load all images from a folder and display all of them in one CSS box (in html).

I want to make all the images like a video or gif maybe.

So each image will appear alternately until the last image is displayed.

Here is my php code :

**camera.php**

```
<?php 

$img_dir = "image/";
$images = scandir($img_dir);
$html = '';
$html .='<ul>';

foreach($images as $img) { 
    if($img === '.' || $img === '..') {continue;}         

    if (  (preg_match('/.jpg/',$img))  ||  (preg_match('/.gif/',$img)) || (preg_match('/.tiff/',$img)) || (preg_match('/.png/',$img)) ){                

        $html .='<li><img src="'.$img_dir.$img.'" ></li>' ; 
    } else { continue; }    
} 

    $html .='</ul>' ; 

    echo $html ;

?>
```

Here is my jquery code:

**jquery.custom.js**

```
jQuery('document').ready(function() {
  $.ajax({            
     url: "camera.php", 
    type: "POST",          
    dataType: "HTML", 
        success: function( data ) { 
    jQuery('body').append(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, data ) {        
    alert ('Ajax request Failed.');    
    }
    }); 
});
```

Here is my CSS box :

```
 #myGallery{
  position:relative;
  width:800px; /* Set your image width */
  height:500px; /* Set your image height */
}
```

I can make all of the images appear , but I don't know how to display all of them in the CSS box and make all of them  like a video.

*I have 200 photos anyway.*

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why don't you use any of the existing libraries for that? not that I wish to encourage you not to code yourself but making a video out of images is not an everyday thing, why re-invent the wheel

Comment: make a video... you can put all images on top of eachother with position:absolute and z-index:1 and then in javascript you can do a set_interval where you set a +1 z-index on the increasing index image... if that makes sense :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For camera.php, you need to return the data in a format in which your ajax call can read it properly.  Assuming that the call to images is returning correctly, you could do the following:

---

## **camera.php**

```
$img_dir = "image/";
$images = scandir($img_dir);

$pictures = array();
foreach($images as $img) { 
    // Not sure how these are returning, so I'm making a guess after looking at your code
    $picture = array(
        "img" => $img_dir.$img
    );
    $pictures[] = $picture;
}

echo json_encode($pictures);
```

---

For the jQuery, you need to specify your dataType as json for it to return correctly.  You also need to append the desired html and data to the body on a success return, and then call a function for the animation when that is done.

## **jquery.custom.js**

```
jQuery('document').ready(function() {

    var i = 0;

    var request = $.ajax({            
        url: "camera.php", 
        type: "POST", 
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(pictures){
            var html = '<ul'>;
            $.each(pictures, function(idx, picture){
                html += '<li><img src="'+picture.img+'"></li>'
            });
            html += '</ul>';
            $('body').append(html);
       }
    });

    request.done({
        loopThruImg();
    });

    function loopThruImg() {
        var li = $('li');
        li.eq(i).animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 100, function () {
            li.eq(i).delay(1000).animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, 100, function () {
                i = i < (li.length - 1) ? i+1 : 0;
                loopThruImg(i);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

---

## Some helpful CSS

```
   ul {
        list-style-type:none;
        position: relative;
    }
    li {
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        opacity:0;
    }
```

[JSFiddle for the animation](http://jsfiddle.net/MJXsW/)

[Awesome Stackoverflow answer that I borrowed heavily from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960471/passing-data-back-from-php-to-ajax)