# Pass select option value to PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have form with two select inputs, what I need to do, is when user choose option from this select, then the value of this option must pass to the function, which will return second select input. So it will looks like (for example):

```
<select name="firstselect">
<option value="1">Var 1</option>
<option value="2">Var 2</option>
</select>
```

And there will be a second select, but this input must be returned by the PHP function, which looks like:

```
<?php echo secondselect($firstselect); ?>
```

So when user select option with value var1, then the echo should look like:

```
<?php echo secondselect(1); ?>
```

But I must do it without page reloading, it is possible?
I know I can make few second select inputs and just show or hide them on change value of first select, but finally there will be a 50+ options, so better will be changing variable in php function.

Comment: With `Google` `Search` `jquery` `ajax` again `Google` `Search`

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=php+ajax+cascading+dropdown&oq=php+ajax+cascading+dropdown&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.8975j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 . Although, even with 50 options, doing it in Javascript only would still be quicker than making an ajax call to the server in order for PHP to return the values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data back from php to ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960471/passing-data-back-from-php-to-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot imagine the case when you need to do this on PHP.

And without reloading the page.

On JavaScript... Like this:

```js
    function secondselect(_first_select){
     var out=null;
     var select_value=$('[name=firstselect]').val();
     $('[name=firstselect] option').each(function(){

      if($(this).val()!=select_value){
        out=$(this).val();
      }
     });
     return out;
    }

    $('[name=firstselect]').change(function(){
      alert('second value of select : ' + secondselect(  $(this).val() ));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select name="firstselect">
  <option value="1">Var 1</option>
  <option value="2">Var 2</option>
</select>
```